# Error in combining date and time from submitted form to insert in MySQL as single datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am getting date and time from submitted form as separate entities. I am combining them and then inserting in MySQL `datetime` type column but I get always as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Here is a snap of my code while I was experimenting:

```
$time=$_POST['date'].' '.$_POST['time'];
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i A', $time);
$mysqltime = $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

var_dump($description);
var_dump($datetime);

$sql = "update vstatus set description=:description, status=2, time=:time where id=:id";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':time',strtotime($datetime),PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This is the `var_dump` result :

```
string(31) "Moving from Noida to Aurangabad" object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-18 16:00:00" 
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
  ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Probably I am able to make the `datetime` object correct as seen in `var_dump` but missing the last step. Any help please.

Comment: `$time` should be `$mysqltime`. You can delete this question.

Comment: You're making the effort to use DateTime objects to create `$mysqltime`, so why are you using `strtotime($time)` in your SQL query instead of `$mysqltime`?

Comment: Its just a snap at some point of time while I was experimenting. I have pieces but not sure which one to fit where.... so need some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: `strtotime` returns `unix_timestamp`, try to bind `$mysqltime` instead of `strtotime($datetime)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained in the comments. Use

```
$query->bindParam(':time',$mysqltime,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

instead of

```
$query->bindParam(':time',strtotime($datetime),PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, I tried that one earlier but didn't work if I looked correctly. Probably, I was in too much hurry. My bad. Thanks.